# UITextField how to make the .text always displaying '$' sign while typing numbers on the right side?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ios9

I have a UITextField and I'm taking some input which are dollars in this care. I need to implement how to always be present the '$' sign after I'm typing the numbers (I mean the '$' to the right (not to the left) of my cursor because I will be writing the code for the Euro (€) sign as well). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UITextField delegate or listen the notification, like `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.
In these method, check the text and add '$'.

Since '$' should be at the correct position, I suggest use UITextField property `selectedTextRange` to calculate the position, and After that use `setSelectedTextRange` to move the cursor to the correct place.

```
UITextPosition * tp = [self.passwordTextField positionFromPosition:self.passwordTextField.beginningOfDocument  offset:self.passwordTextField.text.length - @"$".length];
UITextRange *sr = [self.passwordTextField textRangeFromPosition:tp toPosition:tp];
```

I think the `sr` is the selectedTextRange's value.

Comment: @childrenOurForture I'm within a closure addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler configuring UIAlertController. I have a notification center inside and listening for UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification. But I'm having troubles to implement the '$' or '€' sign always to be on the right of the cursor when I'm typing the values in real time :( Can you give me some more hints bro? Do I need to replace somehow the cursor to the left side of the '€' for example for every newValue?

Comment: one more thing bro, what's the method equivalent to setSelectedTextRange? I'm in Swift 2.1.1 and I can't find it :(

Comment: @BradSmith In swift, it is `selectedTextRange`, just use `xxx.selectedTextRange = xxx`, does it work?

Comment: bro, I'm stuck onto setting the selectedTextRange property. I have created a substring getting the end value of the text and removing the € sign by 2 (considering the 'blank space'). But this property accepts UITextPosition and I'm having an index of the substring only. I'm stuck on this. But, for proving I'm on the right track, i tried using selectedTextRange = textField.textRangeFromPosition(textField.beginningOfDocument, toPosition: textField.beginningOfDocument) and it was working, except it was moving the cursor always in front. Now I need somehow to manage to create this range :(

Comment: Great bro, this was all I was looking for. It's clean, compact and concise, no dirty long codes :D

Comment: Hey bro, It's me again. Can you tell me if there's any method to check when the clear button is pressed on a .DecimalPad keyboard? I'm still within the textFieldConfiguratorHandler closure and I'm listening for UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification. I need to implement when user press clear button to removeAll() characters within the string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that add a label and set its text to '$'.observe the text of textField,when user inputed,update the label frame. like this:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 20))
label.text = "$"
label.font = contentTextField.font
label.textColor = textField.textColor
textField.superview?.addSubview(label)

textField.addTarget(self, action: "yourFunc", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

func yourFunc(sender:UITextField) {
    // calculate the width of sender.text
    // update the frame of label
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this UITextField delegate method and I think this will work for you.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0

if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount){
  return false
}

var cleanString: String = ""

if let text = textField.text{

  let cleanStringAry = text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet) as NSArray

  cleanString = cleanStringAry.componentsJoinedByString("")

}

var cellAmount = 0

if cleanString.characters.count > 0{
  cellAmount = Int(cleanString)!
}

if let fff:String = string{

  if fff.characters.count > 0{

    cellAmount = cellAmount * 10 + Int(fff)!

  }else{
    cellAmount = cellAmount / 10
  }


}


let amount = NSNumber(float: Float(cellAmount)/100.0)

let currencyFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "\u{20AC}"
currencyFormatter.positiveSuffix = "\u{20AC}"
currencyFormatter.paddingPosition = .AfterSuffix
currencyFormatter.negativeSuffix = "\u{20AC}"
currencyFormatter.negativeFormat = "-¤#,##0.00"

let result = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(amount)
if result == "0.00\u{20AC}"{
  textField.text = ""
}else{
  textField.text = currencyFormatter.stringFromNumber(amount)

}

return false
}
```

Comment: I think is not necessary all of that code for my project bro. What I need to do, is to set the selectRangeProperty which will move the cursor to the left in front of the € by minus nth substring index. I'm having some problems to set the selectRangeProperty which accepts UITextPosition